# How can I get all the dates within a week of a certain day using datetime?

Tags: python, date, datetime, date-math

I have some measurements that happened on specific days in a dictionary. It looks like

`date_dictionary['YYYY-MM-DD'] = measurement`.

I want to calculate the variance between the measurements within 7 days from a given date.  When I convert the date strings to a `datetime.datetime`, the result looks like a tuple or an array, but doesn't behave like one.

Is there an easy way to generate all the dates one week from a given date?  If so, how can I do that efficiently?

Comment: Show us more code... how do you convert? how does it behave? how do you expect it to behave? what do you mean by "variance"?

Comment: Variance is a statistic.  I convert the strings by executing `t = date_string.split('-')` and `datetime.datetime( year = int(t[0]), month = int(t[1]), day = int(t[2]) )`.  I want datetime to behave like an array or list, so I could say `t=datetime.datetime(2015,02,11)`  and  `t+(0,0,7) = datetime.datetime(2015,02,18)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using - [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) . Example -

```
>>> from datetime import datetime,timedelta
>>> d = datetime.strptime('2015-07-22','%Y-%m-%d')
>>> for i in range(1,8):
...     print(d + timedelta(days=i))
...
2015-07-23 00:00:00
2015-07-24 00:00:00
2015-07-25 00:00:00
2015-07-26 00:00:00
2015-07-27 00:00:00
2015-07-28 00:00:00
2015-07-29 00:00:00
```

You do not actually need to print it, `datetime` object + `timedelta` object returns a `datetime` object. You can use that returned `datetime` object directly in your calculation.

Answer (score 4):

Using datetime, to generate all 7 dates following a given date, including the the given date, you can do:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(...)
week_dates = [ dt + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(7) ]
```

There are libraries providing nicer APIs for performing datetime/date operations, most notably `pandas` (though it includes much much more). See [pandas.date_range](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html).